# Menu Bar Maintenance

Tags: software-recommendation, menu-bar

I grow weary of all of the icons running in my menu bar. At this point, most of the menus on the left side are overlapped by icons from the right. Is there a good app for fixing this? I know I can drag the system ones off to the desktop and delete them, but installed apps are another story.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [Bartender](http://www.macbartender.com), which allows you to control what displays where in the menu bar.

[image: Bartender Menu Bar]

> #### Organize your menu bar apps
>
> - Lets you tidy your menu bar apps how you want.
> - See your menu bar apps when you want.
> - Hide the apps you need to run, but do not need to see.
> - Have the clean looking menu bar you want.
> - Rearrange your menu bar items as you wish.